# $.mobile.changePage mutlipage hidden after second

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use multipage (on the same page) with jquery mobile and $.mobile.changePage transition slide.
Obviously I need to go back on pages that I already open via changePage function.

It works perfectly on Firefox but not on safari or chrome.

On safari and chrome when I come back on a page that I already opened then, the page is displayed few milliseconds and the all the page is hidden. If I use "alert('stop');" just after the changePage function, then the page is displayed, "stop" is displayed, the page is still displayed until I close the popup "stop", then the page is hidden.

I found the following code on another page linked to transition issue and you will see how it happens. 
if you go back on page that has been open once, then the page is hidden:

http://jsfiddle.net/GYAB7/2/

FYI: if I use

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#mypage", {
        transition: "none",
        reverse: true,
        changeHash: false
    });
```

instead of

```
 $.mobile.changePage( "#mypage", {
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: true,
        changeHash: false
    });
```

for the transition parameters, then it works fine (but it is not what I want)

Thank you.

PS: page where I found the code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491510/jquery-mobile-changepage-with-swipe-transition)

Comment: After lot of test, it looks like that if I have inside my main page :
`//PageA
link to go to page B : $.mobile.changePage( "#PageB", {transition: "none",changeHash: false});
//Page B
link to go to page A : $.mobile.changePage( "#PageA", {transition: "slide",changeHash: false});`
**then it is working OK**

Comment: But if I have in my main page :
`//PageA
link to go to page B : $.mobile.changePage( "#PageB", {transition: "slide",changeHash: false});

//Page B
link to go to page A : $.mobile.changePage( "#PageA", {transition: "slide",changeHash: false});`

**then it is not working** => when I go back on page A, the page is displayed for few milliseconds and then the page is blank/no displayed.

Comment: To illustrate my point :

Run [http://jsfiddle.net/sz9pjbcv/](http://jsfiddle.net/sz9pjbcv/) on chrome vs firefox

When you come back on first page then the page is hidden on chrome